# Grab reference to static members or functions that has custom attribute attached

Tags: unity

I am trying to create a custom attribute that I can attach to either variables or functions, such that I could grab all references somewhere else in code.

Example

```
[Attribute1]                        //custom attribute
public static int speed = 1;        //dummy variable
[Attribute1]                        //custom attribute
public static int acceleration = 1; //dummy variable
[Attribute2]                        //custom attribute
public static int count = 1;        //dummy variable

[Attribute3]
public static void DummyFunction() {...}
```

and from somewhere else, be able to do something along the lines of

```
var allAttributeReferences = GetAllAttributes("Attribute1");
allAttributeReferences[0] = 10;

var allAttributeReferences2 = GetAllAttributes("Attribute2");
foreach (var reference in allAttributeReferences2)
{
    reference = 0;
}

var allAttributeReferences3 = GetAllAttributes("Attribute3")[0];
allAttributeReferences3(); //Assume it is a function, and invoke function.
```

Is this even remotely possible? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [System.Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx):

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var types = assembly.GetTypes();

foreach (var t in types)
{
    var fields = t.GetFields(); //or GetMethods(), etc etc
    foreach (var f in fields)
    {               
        if (f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ATTRIBUTE), true).Any())
        {
            if (f.IsStatic)
            {
                // do stuff with f
            }
        }
    }
}
```